# Cron Expression - Run every hour after a start time

Tags: quartz-scheduler, cronexpression

I want to run a cron job every hour after a certain start time. Currently my cron job expression is

```
cronExpression = seconds + " " + minutes +  " " +   hours +"/1" + " " + " * * ? *" ;
```

(seconds, minutes, hours are passed in by the user selection)

The job starts at the right time and runs every hour until midnight but then stops until the hour on the next day and then resumes. How do I get the job to continuously run and not stop at midnight?

I understand I can change the expression to

```
cronExpression = seconds + " " + minutes +  " " * * * ? *" ;
```

but then it will not take into account the start time. It will just run at every hour.

Thanks in advance,
Rich

Comment: How often is the job to run?

Comment: I want the job to run hourly forever until the user stops the job.

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean you want the job to start at the given time and then run once hourly forever? If so, I don't think a cron expression is the right approach.

If you're using a scheduler it should be straightforward to start the job and run forever at a given interval. For example, here's a snippet from the Quartz scheduler docs for [JobBuilder](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.7/org/quartz/JobBuilder.html):

```
     JobDetail job = newJob(MyJob.class)
         .withIdentity("myJob")
         .build();

     Trigger trigger = newTrigger() 
         .withIdentity(triggerKey("myTrigger", "myTriggerGroup"))
         .withSchedule(simpleSchedule()
             .withIntervalInHours(1)
             .repeatForever())
         .startAt(futureDate(10, MINUTES))
         .build();

     scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

Answer (score 0):

Run a wrapper every hour which runs your job if the current time is after your start time.

For example,

```
case $(date +%H) in 
    09 |1[0-6] ) pingcheck ;;
esac
```

would run `pingcheck` (whatever that is :-) between 09:00 and 16:59.

Answer (score 0):

Use your own expression

> cronExpression = seconds + " " + minutes +  " " * * * ? *" ;

with the startAt(your start time) method() mentioning the start time of the trigger. This start time will implicitely tell the quartz when the trigger will start coming into effect.